# Maximal determinants of zero-one matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, determinant, discrete-optimization

1. Is it possible to find the maximal determinant of matrices in $\{0,1\}^{n \times n}$?
2. If so, what do matrices with maximal determinant look like?

For example, when $n=3$,  it's not hard to see that the maximal determinant is $2$, as there are only $6$ terms involved and one can brute-force it. In particular, one of such matrices is the following

\begin{pmatrix}0&1&1\\1&0&1\\1&1&0\end{pmatrix}

However, I have no idea how to generalize this argument to higher dimension.

Comment: See [Hadamard's maximum determinant problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HadamardsMaximumDeterminantProblem.html).

Comment: An extensive discussion with some links can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/320965/determinants-of-binary-matrices.)